# Prevent Private sub from calling function - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, volatile

I have now come to the understanding that my Private sub calls my UDF because my UDF has `Application.Volatile = True`. I can therefore prevent it from happening, by setting it to `Application.Volatile = False` instead.

**Problem**

Without having Volatile set to `True` in my function, it won't update, which is key in my sheet. And as earlier mentioned, I would like my private sub to stop calling my function, since it pretty much stops my loop from happening.

**Goal**

I would therefore like to know, whether it is possible to prevent my Private sub from calling my function, since it is placed in very different areas.

My private sub inserts a new value in B19, whereas my function is placed in A2.

Thank you in advance

As requested here is the code:

```
Sub UpdateSheets()
Dim WS_count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet

Today = Date

WS_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For I = 1 To WS_count
    If I = 1 Then
        Else
        Set sht = Sheets(I)
            LnLAddress = sht.Range("A:A").Find("Lease end lessee:", , LookIn:=xlValues).Address(False, False, xlA1)
            LnLOff = sht.Range(LnLAddress).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
            LnLVal = sht.Range(LnLOff).Value
            NtceAddress = sht.Range("A:A").Find("Notice:", , LookIn:=xlValues).Address(False, False, xlA1)
            NtceOff = sht.Range(NtceAddress).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
            NtceVal = sht.Range(NtceOff).Value
            On Error GoTo Ending:
            NtceVal = Left(NtceVal, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", NtceVal) - 1)
            LnLVal = DateSerial(Year(LnLVal), Month(LnLVal) - NtceVal, Day(LnLVal))
            LnLYear = Year(LnLVal)
            On Error GoTo 0
                If LnLVal <= Today Then
                    AutoExtAddress = sht.Range("A:A").Find("Automatical extension of contract", , LookIn:=xlValues).Address(False, False, xlA1)
                    AutoExtOff = sht.Range(AutoExtAddress).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
                    AutoExtVal = sht.Range(AutoExtOff).Value
                    AutoExt = Left(AutoExtVal, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", AutoExtVal) - 1)
                    LnLNewVal = DateSerial(Year(LnLVal) + AutoExt, Month(LnLVal) + NtceVal, Day(LnLVal))
                    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                    sht.Range(LnLOff).Value = LnLNewVal
                    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'loop through functions starts here...
                End If
    End If
Ending:
On Error GoTo 0
Next I

End Sub
```

And here the functions:

```
Function SHEETNAME(number As Long) As String
Application.Volatile True
    SHEETNAME = Sheets(number).Name
End Function

Function NxtShtNm(number As Long) As String
Application.Volatile True
    NxtShtNm = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + number - 1).Name
End Function
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code or a [mcve]. Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that you already have. Without that, it's difficult to answer your question, and will therefore likely be closed as being too broad.

Comment: I have now inserted the code and functions.

Comment: My sheet is an overview, whereas sheet 1 has the overview. Then for each individual agreement, I have assigned a sheet to it. In these individual sheets, all of the data is placed, whereas I have made the two functions for dynamically being able to "Hyperlink". The function called `Function SHEETNAME(number As Long) As String` is the function, which is in the individual sheets.

Comment: ...so all this code is to add hyperlinks dynamically?  Are you aware of the [`HYPERLINK` worksheet function](https://support.office.com/article/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f)?  In my experience when someone's had to use `Application.Volatile` to make a UDF "work properly", there's almost always a better/more organized/more efficient way to accomplish the same task.

Comment: I am using this without the Hyperlink function, which is available by standard... I have asssigned the function to show the name of the sheet, by what number it is to the right of the overview. If so I could do this more efficient without UDF, or Volatile, it would be nice :)

Comment: Perhaps if you gave an example of the relevant data you have, and what you need in the end (ie., hyperlink url built from what?) then someone could suggest a much more straightforward way to make this happen.

Comment: It hyperlinks to the sheets within the same workbook. And that’s just about it :)

Comment: This worksheet function returns the current worksheet name: `=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)` (based off of the [`CELL("filename")` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) which returns filename + sheet name.)

Comment: ...and to answer your question, I don't think there's a way to do what you're describing, and it would be awfully convoluted to implement anyhow.  I think you need to go back to the drawing board on this one.

Comment: I'm already using that one, to determine the name of the Store within the individual sheets. What I need to do, is that lets say the first sheet is called "Overview", then we have "Store A" and "Store BE". If I then afterwards get a Store "BA" then my overview should automatic know, that when I have placed this between "Store A" and "Store BE", then it should also be between these in the overview.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly you want to [**Sort Worksheets Alphanumerically by Name**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/sort-worksheets-alphanumerically-by-name).    (Also with my previous comment about the `CELL` function, note that it can also be used to return the names of other sheets if required.)

Comment: And how do I do that @ashleedawg, If I may ask? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183488/discussion-between-patrick-s-and-ashleedawg).

Comment: Turn off calculation while your sub runs.

Comment: Whenever I turn it back on, it displays "#Value" in every cell. Can this be set back to normal once again?

Answer (score 0):

later on came to know a better solution, without making UDF's...
I deleted my functions, since they only made problems within my sheet.

Then I made a named range, from the name manager, calling it "sheetlist"
After this I assigned this formula to what it refers to: `=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1);1;FIND("]";GET.WORKBOOK(1));"")&T(NOW())`

Making a formula in the cells, where I need to reference the workbooks: `=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("#'" & INDEX(sheetlist;ROW()) & "'!A1";INDEX(sheetlist;ROW()));"")`

Now it references the sheets in order, and assigning:
`Private Sub WorkSheet_Activate()
ActiveWorksheet.Calculate
End sub`
to the overview sheet, has made the trick of updating itself :)